# Customized UISlider Minimum Track Image smaller than MaximumTrackImage

Tags: iphone, uislider

I am trying to create a UISlider with custom graphics but the issue i am facing is that the slider fill value is bigger in height than slider base value. Please see screen shot for this.

[image]

And how it should look like is as seen in picture below,

[image]

The code that i am using is pasted below,

```
[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolKnob"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolBase"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolFill"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make both images the same height, perhaps you can add transparency to the base or fill value so it appears to be smaller / bigger. I would also play with the CapInset to determine that right values for you. Do some research on the function resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake.

```
UIImage* minTrack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VolFill"];
minTrack = [minTrack resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:minTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Good luck.